# Apply Bootstrap Tokenfield on a Class instead of Id

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-tokeninput, bootstrap-tokenfield

I have some dynamically generated form input fields where I want to apply Bootstrap tokenfield.

It is possible to apply tokeninput on a class using the following code. Tokeninput is applied on all input fields with class 'someclass'. 'someurl' fetches the remote JSON data.

```
    $(document).on('focusin', '.someclass', function()
    {
      $(this).tokenInput('someurl');
    });
```

I would like to achieve similar functionality using tokenfield. Kindly help.

Comment: when is the dynamic input field generated? is it a row on a table?